# how to change vertical query result to horizontal in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, pivot

this is the result from a complicated query with many joins :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1LTV.png)

What I want is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X1Hj.png)

How do I accomplish this ?

tried to use pivot, but I am not trying to aggregate anything.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Sample input???  Expected output???

Answer (score 0):

This should help you to get to the correct logic. You need to use nested selects.

```
SELECT id, 
       visit, 
       date, 
       weight, 
       height 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               visit, 
               date, 
               Sum(weight) AS weight, 
               0           AS height 
        FROM   table 
        WHERE  type = ‚weight‘ 
        GROUP  BY id, 
                  visit, 
                  date 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT id, 
               visit, 
               date, 
               0           AS weight, 
               Sum(height) AS height 
        FROM   table 
        WHERE  type = ‚height‘ 
        GROUP  BY id, 
                  visit, 
                  date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with an EAV table, with the combination of Member_id, Visit_no and Date being the entity, Type being the attribute and, well, Value the value.

One option is to aggregate your data, so as to get from four source rows to two result rows.

```
select
  member_id, visit_no, date,
  max(case when type = 'weight' then value end) as weight,
  max(case when type = 'height' then value end) as height
from mytable
group by member_id, visit_no, date
order by member_id, visit_no, date;
```

This is called "cconditional aggregation", because we aggregate on conditions. The maximum value for all rows of the group that have the attribute 'weight' is just the one weight value, because there is only one row per group and attribute. This is what makes you say you are not aggregating, but in SQL this is an aggregation and we must use `MIN` or `MAX` (or even `SUM` or `AVG` if we want to confuse the reader) to get the one value.

The same can be done with the `PIVOT` clause.

Another approach is to make this two data sets, one for the weights, one for the heights, that you then join:

```
with
  weights as
  (
    select member_id, visit_no, date, value as weight
    from mytable
    where type = 'weight'
  ),
  heights as
  (
    select member_id, visit_no, date, value as height
    from mytable
    where type = 'height'
  )
select *
from weights full outer join heights using (member_id, visit_no, date)
order by member_id, visit_no, date;
```